# How to wrap a tomtom map into a bootstrap container

Tags: api, maps, gis, tomtom

So I have rendered the tomtom map into a bootstrap container as indicated below and everything seems to work fine [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nROAb.png)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
   var map = tomtom.L.map('map', {
                  key: '<my key>',
                  basePath: 'tomtom',
                  source: 'raster',
                  center: KenyaCoordinates,
                  zoom: 6.4,
    });
```

Problem is when you interract with the rendered map, it somehow resizes, overrides all the other elements and covers the entire screen as shown in [this other image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acjwt.png)

Comment: sorry but can't understand your issue. Can you, for example, record a video/gif of that behavior? If you don't want to share your code of course.